# push notification is working in development version but not in production (ios12 and iOS13)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a small issue with my xamarin-app. On my ios12 and ios13-iPhones i get push notifications in the development version but not in the production version. Even when i change in the entitlements.plist the key 'aps-environment' from 'development' to 'production'. 
Now my questions: Are there requirements that only apply to the release version? (eq. special permissions,...)
what about the entitlements.plist? Must the file be specified in the custom permissions? It seems that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Are you using App Center for push notifications?

Comment: No. The pushes are coming via apple push from firebase.

Comment: Ok, I haven't used firebase. But I know that App Center uses different configurations for dev and prod. It's a PITA as (like in your situation) the only way around it would be to have two versions of the app with different bundle IDs if you wanted to run and test both. Might be worth checking Firebase to see if it has similar restrictions.

Comment: iOS push notification use different push certifications under develop and production mode, did you config that?

Comment: Yes, i did. Permissions for develop and production are the same.

Comment: Can you please check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-ios#set-up-apns) for the points.  Did you select Sandbox for initial development or Production for production version of your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to your questions:
There are no other requirements of special permissions that only apply to the release version.
About the entitlements.plist - what you did was enough.
No file needs to be specified in the custom permissions.

The reason you are not able to get it to work has to do with using the right certificates.

There are other underlying requirements by the server sending the push notifications, but since you are using firebase, that should already be covered.